# Matlab convert double to float

Tags: matlab, double, rounding

As far as I know double precision is standard for MatLab but
I want to write a program which finds out the smallest possible a (which is in double precision ), so that float(1+a)>1.
Is there a function to convert double precision to single precision ?

Comment: Use the duplicate post but make sure you initialize your variable to `single` to enforce single precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you probably want eps, see:

```
help eps
1+eps > 1
```

or to convert a double to single simply cast it in single

```
A = 1;
singleA = single(A);
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have stated that we aren't allowed to use eps. So I gonna try single(A) and see whether that works.  Just one more question. Let´s say a is the smallest positive double value,  how can I get the next smallest positive double and so on ?

Comment: a*2 gives you the next smallest I assume? and a*3 gives you the third?

Comment: @XPenguen: What you are asking for is exactly the definition of `eps`. As you are not allowed to use it, I recommend to implement the function yourself.

Comment: I would try to solve the problem by  starting with a number x for which I know single(1+x)=1 and then try the same with x+realmin,x+2*realmin and so on. The problem is, I need a decent approximation for eps, otherwise the loop will take forever.

Comment: "aren't allowed" implies homework.  Is this the case?

Comment: You are understanding the floating point precision wrong, x+realmim is x unless x is close to zero. There is no need to approximate eps, it is known.

Comment: The single precision floating point format is implemented IEEE-754 standard. You should be able to write a nice function for this by reading the standard or this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) summary or other references on the web.